# Подскажите, пожалуйста, как убрать сдвиг (возможность прокрутки) сайта влево в мобильной версии?

Tags: html, css, css3, html5, адаптивная-верстка

http://oliver.sliding.com.ua/

Проблема появляется только на мобильном. Когда тестирую просто на маленьком разрешении все нормально. Блоков, которые вылазят за пределы - не видно.

Comment: у вас слайдер с картинками залазит. А именно картинка, которая еще не показана и находится справа

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Удаляете класс "row", убираются отрицательные отступы , скролл пропадет http://prntscr.com/ih8dhj

Comment: Точно! Спасибо, помогло!

Comment: А как убрать этот скролл в мобильной версии если все таки необходимо спрятать часть блока, чтобы при нажатии он появлялся полностью?

Answer (score 0):

Ну в целом, у вас первая ошибка идет из-за слайдера `#action-mobile`.  То есть javascript назначает неверную ширину для элементов слайдера, из-за этого получается ошибка. Первое что я бы предложил сделать:

```
.slick-next {
     right: 10px;// или другое значение
}
```

Потому что в данный момент эта кнопка, уходит  за пределы видимости экрана.

Comment: Да, верно дело в слайдерах, причем в обоих (отключил оба - проблема ушла). Отключение стрелок не помогает(